# iOS Swift Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When i run my application, after clicking a GO a button it takes me to login page which is fine, but when i click login it crashes and highlights a line of code in the Apple delegate file which is this....

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { and then shows
>   an error which says... 2017-09-11 16:29:43.502 Smart Home System
>   Application[1832:151828] Unknown class
>   _TtC29Smart_Home_System_Application14ViewController in Interface Builder file. 2017-09-11 16:29:51.116 Smart Home System
>   Application[1832:151828] Unknown class
>   _TtC29Smart_Home_System_Application14ViewController in Interface Builder file. 2017-09-11 16:30:01.197 Smart Home System
>   Application[1832:151828] -[UIViewController LoginButton:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f82503390 2017-09-11
>   16:30:01.217 Smart Home System Application[1832:151828] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   LoginButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f82503390'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104a12b0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000101da2141 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000104a82134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104999840
>   ___forwarding_** + 1024   4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049993b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x0000000102275d82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>     6   UIKit                               0x00000001023fa5ac
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     7   UIKit                               0x00000001023fa8c7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
>     8   UIKit                               0x00000001023f9802
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618    9   UIKit                               0x00000001022e37ea -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707     10  UIKit
>   0x00000001022e4f00 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114  11  UIKit
>   0x0000000102291a84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352  12  UIKit
>   0x0000000102a755d4 **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
>     13  UIKit                               0x0000000102a6d532
>   __handleEventQueue + 1122     14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049b8c01
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010499e0cf
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527   16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010499d5ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911     17  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010499d016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406     18  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010691da24 GSEventRunModal + 62   19  UIKit
>   0x0000000102274134 UIApplicationMain + 159    20  Smart Home System
>   Application       0x00000001017c9347 main + 55    21  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001059b265d start + 1  22  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

How do i fix this Please??

Comment: Please format properly.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error description:

`UIViewController` is missing function `LoginButton:`, and some part of your code is trying to invoke this function. Thus, crash is happening. I am not able to read the crash properly (since its not formatted well) - but, from what I can understand - its a touch event (probably on a `UIControl`, like `UIButton`) that's triggering the invocation of `LoginButton:` method. Since the method is not available, its crashing.

`unrecognized selector sent to instance` - specifically means that a function is being invoked which is not available. Also, check connection to this function from your `XIB`

Comment: I have solved the problem thank you

Comment: If this indeed was your problem, please mark the above answer as correct.

Answer (score -1):

Check the connection of your login Button in the storyBoard.. Check if you have any deleted IBoutlets or multiple actions connected.

Comment: I recently deleted an IBoutlets because i had issues earlier but solved that one and then i jumped into this current problem now. And there is only one connection

Comment: I have solved the problem thank you